# Where to store API and Client key in Android Studio project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Android studio project with Google cloud module.
My android module (app) has the dependency on GAE module but it using "android-endpoints" does not give me the constants class from GAE module, and I suppose it is not a good idea to store API key in the java code itself.
So, how should I store the API and different client key in my project? Should I use gradle to put it the android module and reference it from GAE module or vice versa?

Comment: I think some screenshots, folder structures, and a lot more description would help this question. I'm unable to determine what problem you're having or what solution would help you. There are numerous ways to access data from inside your Android application? Is there a reason why you can't create a `Constants` class?